# android listview scroll to number of listitems

Tags: android, listview

I am using Listview, i want to scroll down to list's 10 item when view get loaded, how can do that ????

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `yourListView.setSelection(position)`

Comment: I am using ArrayAdapter to display custom listitems when user click on more search results in my application i add more items and call 
<br/>
eventsList.setSelection(15);
<br/>
but it is not working b/c i am having getview method which get called after

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
mMessageList.addAll(result);
mMessageArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

mMessageListView.clearFocus();
mMessageListView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mMessageListView.setSelection(searchedMessagePosition);
    }
});
```