# Why cant I inherit a protected field from android.view?

Tags: java, android, view

I'm trying to override the `offsetTopAndBottom(int offset)` method which is a `View` class method.
But when I try to access the `mTop` or `mBottom` fields, even though they are `protected` in the `View` class, I get an error.

Does anyone know why I would have this kind of access problem ?

For example:

```
CustomView extend android.view.View{

   someOverridenMethod()
   {
       mTop = 10 //error, mTop no resolved as a type
   }
}
```

Comment: a link to the View source code   http://hi-android.info/src/android/view/View.java.html

Comment: Yes, this is odd. Looks like that should be possible. What kind of error do you get?

Comment: as far as i know, it isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `m{variables}` are not accessible. For the life of me I can't remember why, something to do with `m{variables}` not being part of the public API.

I had a similar problem and after days of searching, I pretty much found it to be impossible.

I believe you can try calling `View.layout(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`;

this will ultimately set the `mTop` value, at which point you can call `getTop()`. However there is a method to the madness and you will find that a number of other methods will be called as a result. So whether this actually helps you or not is well...to be seen.

Comment: I would consider re-evaluating your thinking if your current solution is based on editing mTop or any mValue for that matter. I went back to the tutorials and tried to stick to the onDraw() and on{method} that they suggested you stick to using.

Comment: i'm trying to make a ListView start around a different offset.. if you have anu idea about how can i do it pls share :)

Comment: scrollY or setPosition(row10), is this what your asking? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952630/android-listview-scroll-to-number-of-listitems

Answer (score 0):

According to the [View javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) there is no member or method called *mTop*.

Comment: Pls check the Link added hi-android.info/src/android/view/View.java.html

Comment: I confirm there is a protected member mTop. Check the source code if in doubt.

Comment: Check the android JAR you are building with. Mine does not have any non final protected members exposed. In general if it's not in the javadocs don't try to use it.

Comment: @Andrew White: you are right! however still don't get why it is present in sources as a protected member and is unavailable during inheritance at the same time..

Comment: I looked for a reasons. Google Romain Guy and see if you can find a post that explains it. In the meantime, honestly it isn't possible, even though it looks like it should be. Its something to do with those members not being part of the public api.

Comment: Correct, those are not part of the public API.  If you are looking at the sources, you will see the "@hide" in the comment telling the build system to hide it from the public API.  The reason for this is that allowing direct access to member variables results in later maintenance problems: for example if an application changes the value there, it is implicitly relying on implementation details of how the value is used.  (A later version of the platform would have no way to catch when it is set by an app, so would have to assume it always needs to read the value.)